# Could akka actor reply message in different case

Tags: akka, actor, akka-http

I am using Akka HTTP and have a AnswerActor, I want to do following thing.

```
class AnswerActor() extends Actor {
  var requestMap = mutable.Map[String, ActorRef]()
  ...
  override def receive: Receive = {
// I want to store sender() here instead of reply in this case, because my reply is not available at this moment
    case message: M1 => requestMap.put(sender().path.name -> sender()) 

// I want to reply when I receive M2, my reply is available now
    case message: M2 => requestMap.get(...) ! MyReply
```

I use `val ans = Await.result(questionActor ? M1)` , and another actor to send message `M2` to `AnswerActor` but there is no reply, only if I add some reply in following(case M1) it could work

```
case message: M1 => requestMap.put(name -> sender())
    sender() ! something
```

Is it possible to implement the logic above in akka?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You still need your first actor to answer if you're using the ask pattern (with the ?). so after the `requestMap.put(name -> sender())` you'll need to send back an answer. Still it's not clear where the variable `name` comes from.

Comment: @IsmailH I have updated the question, maybe your solution could not solve it?

Comment: Are you sending M1 and M2 to the same actor ?  the same instance `questionActor` ?

Comment: @IsmailH turns out it is due to my wrong code to call `ask` method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suspect, from your limited description, is that `M2` is not being received by `questionActor` after it receives `M1` (or at least it's not being received soon enough after for the ask to timeout).  In general there is no guarantee that a message sent from actor A to actor B will be received before a message sent from actor C to actor B, regardless of whether C sent the message before or after A (the ordering guarantee is that if actor A sends messages 1 then 2 then 3 to actor B, 3 will not be received before 1 or 2 is received and 2 will not be received before 1 is received).

In general, it's not a good idea to use `Await` in an actor or in a stream, since that prevents the actor from processing any message.  Within an actor, it's better to use the pipe pattern:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

(questionActor ? M1).pipeTo(context.self)
```

If you wanted to ignore (or stash) every message besides `MyReply`, you could then immediately use `context.become` to install a new message handler which ignores/stashes as desired.

Within a stream, it's generally best to use the `mapAsync` or, in some cases (Akka 2.6.x only) `ask` stream stage to perform the ask in a non-blocking way.

The use of `Await.result` may also directly be causing your problem, depending on how many cores/vCPUs are available and the Akka version: the blocking may prevent any actor or stream stage from getting CPU time.

Comment: Great analysis, and my issue turns out it is due to my wrong code to call `ask` method...